# Docker Image Registry behind IAP proxy

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, google-kubernetes-engine, docker-registry, identity-aware-proxy

I've inherited a system where we have a gitlab Docker image registry hosted in GCP, but it's behind an IAP proxy so I can do a docker pull while connected to our internal network (thanks to firewall rules that bypass the IAP proxy).

Is there any way to do a docker pull against it from the internet? I suspect I need a plugin for `docker login` to make it IAP aware.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: What does "hosted in GCP" actually mean - which service?

Comment: It's on a GKE cluster.

Effectively I have a pod running gitlab which deploys a pod (via helm i believe) for the container registry. I don't that part is relevant though. I think I would have the same problem on a compute instance.

Comment: AFAIK No. The reason is that IAP uses Google Accounts for the Identity Provider. IAP requires OIDC Identity Tokens for authentication. Take a look at `docker login -u oauth2accesstoken -p "$(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" https://[HOSTNAME]` I am not sure if docker login is creating an HTTP Authorization Bearer header which is required for IAP or another form for credentials.

Comment: @JohnHanley That's what i was thinking, though jumping though the docker CLI code is frustrating as it actually makes the request to the docker daemon which then makes the request to the registry. 

I did find that `docker login` 'works' in that it succeeds. But doing a `docker pull` fails as unauthorised.

Comment: It seems in this case a possible way is to reproduce an approach similar to the existing VPN connection from the office: establish VPN between the clients and the registry, or configure bypassing rules for partucular public addresses (if clients do have them).